# Add a period counter on dygraphs label

Tags: r, r-dygraphs

For example, on a dygraph like that:

```
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths)
```

I would like to customize the label as follows. Instead of

Jan, 1974
Feb, 1974
etc.

I would like to see:

Jan, 1974 (1)
Feb, 1974 (2)
etc.

I don't care if the counter is concatenated on the date, I just want to see the period incremental number, as the mouse moves over the series. (Of course without displaying it as a series on the graph)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a customised `valueFormatter`, and use the `row` argument to capture the period number.
Here is an example:

```
library(dygraphs)
library(htmlwidgets)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)

date_counter <- 'function(d,opts, seriesName, dygraph, row, col){
              var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
              date = new Date(d);
              return monthNames[date.getMonth()]+", " +date.getFullYear() + " (" + row.toString() + ")";
}'

dygraph(lungDeaths) %>%
  dyAxis("x",valueFormatter=JS(date_counter))
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack -- make a column in the data but hide the visual cues for that row in the chart:

```
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths, row = 1:length(mdeaths))
dygraph(lungDeaths) %>%
  dySeries("row", strokeWidth = 0, pointSize = 0, color = "white")
```

[image]

Comment: Although the graph is not shown, it exists and, unfortunately, it affects the y-axis boundaries.. (notice the white dot on the x axis, over Jan 1974)